# xdebug not connecting with client?

Tags: xdebug, fedora, selinux

**The xdebug server doesn't connect to any of the clients on port 9000** ie:Netbeans IDE ,debugclient etc.xdebug is shown in phpinfo output.The above clients keep on waiting for the connection to be established.when ever I try to run a php script from the cli it gives the following warning message:

**"PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0"**
 The 9000 port has been opened and shows up in the netstat --numeric-port -l command.
I have no idea what might have gone wrong.I have checked all the configuration files,everything seems ok. Any help will be appreciated.
Section of my configuration files

```
Linux abc.localdomain 3.1.1-2.fc16.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Nov 14 15:46:10 UTC 2011 x86_64 
 This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
 Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
 with Xdebug v2.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by Derick Rethans
[Zend]
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_autostart=On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
```

php_api no. coincides

Xdebug Simple DBGp client (0.10.0)
Copyright 2002-2007 by Derick Rethans.
- libedit support: enabled

Waiting for debug server to connect.

Is it black magic!!

Thank You

Comment: It was actually Selinux not allowing Httpd to connect to other network resources.Setting the boolean for httpd solved the problem.
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on

Answer (score 4):

It was actually Selinux not allowing Httpd to connect to other network resources.

Setting the boolean for httpd solved the problem:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

OS Fedora 16-X_64

Comment: For searchers: ran into this one on CentOS, and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was

```
sudo chcon -R -h -t /path/to/xdebug.so
```

meaning SELinux now allows httpd to execute this shared object.